# How to Open PDF in Browser and modify it and save it?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I am thinking about opening a PDF file with some editable fields in the browser , by which i can modify the PDF file / fill information etc and then save that PDF FORM

Please guide me in a right direction ?

Comment: don't give me nagative score I want only suggestions that it can possible or not.

Comment: Those PDFs will be pre-generated?

Comment: @TheDictator yes can we edit pre-generated pdf is there any way ?

Comment: Then I also agree with @YeshodhanKulKarni you need native app for that. You just can't edit it directly.

Comment: :( ok @TheDictator thanks for look into it

Comment: most welcome.. let me know if anything else is there then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your case Rad PDF can work. It is a PDF Viewer and Editor for ASP.NET by which you can open the PDF with editable fields in browser and can even modify the PDF and save it.
Check the link:- 
 https://www.radpdf.com/demo/easy-integration/ 
and another one is below:-
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PDF-Editor-to-Edit-PDF-5fb73b8d

Hope it will work in your case.
Thanks

Comment: one thing more its not open source.

Comment: yeah @pargat its works need to make custom thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Simple.

PDFs are edited by the native app, in your case may be Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer. You do not have control on anything that happens when the user edits the PDF in a native app context.

Answer (score 0):

Pdf documents come in many flavors (standards). One of them (FDF) matches your usecase very closely. This particular standard allows you to edit a pdf form, on completion (or some other event) it would send the data back to a server, collect a response, and modify the pdf with the incoming data.

Keep in mind though that this standard is not often used. There may be a good reason for that (not a lot of libraries support it).